# MATLAB Editor Tab

Tags: matlab, editor

The Editor of MATLAB has a tab that shows different scripts. The tab can be on the top, bottom , left or right of the editor. I selected hide tab but I cannot show it again to brows between different scripts. Any hit how to make this tab appear again?

Comment: The Tabs Position button on the top View tab?

Comment: Yes. The tabs disappeared and I cannot show them again. Like when you change the tab position. You can select up, down, left, right or disappear. I selected disappear but I cannot show them again

Comment: You need to open an Editor window (with "New script" or something like that), then select the editor and you will get the tabs in the main toolbar- "Editor","Publish","View"- that what @TroyHaskin talked about. There in View, you have "Tabs position" button.

Answer (score 0):

1. Undock editor.
2. Right click on "Switch Windows" icon and then select "Customize" from the menu
3. Then go to "Toolbars" and select "Editor - View"
4. From "Editor - View"  click "Tab Position" which will create an icon for this on the editor at the top right.
5. From this "Tab Position" icon you can select to show the tab on the left, right, top, bottom or hide.